# Move pg_wal directory location/files of postgres 14 database from one drive to another drive in Windows server

Tags: database, postgresql, windows, cmd, mklink

I have a requirement in the Postgres 14 database, which is installed in a Windows server environment.
I want to move the pg_wal directory files from my G drive, where I installed my Postgres 14 database, to my D drive. This is to reduce the read-write IO of the G drive and improve its performance.

I used the symbolic link (mklink) command as given below:

```
mklink /D "D:\pg_wal" "G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal"
```

Here *G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal* is where my pg_wal files are, and I want them to move to *D:\pg_wal*. This is working, and a shortcut folder is getting created, but still, pg_wal files are there in *G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal* location and I want all the pg_wal files to automatically move to *D:\pg_wal* directory without getting filled in the original location (G:\Postgres-14d\data\pg_wal).

In another words, *G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal* directory should be empty, and all the pg_wal files should be collected in *D:\pg_wal* whenever the log files are generated. Or move the entire pg_wal directory from G drive to D Drive.

In this way, I can save space on the G drive and reduce the disk IO. Anyone, please help me get a solution or guide me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing this the wrong way around. Try as follows:

- shut down the PostgreSQL server (service)
- ```bash
  move G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal D:\pg_wal
  ```
- ```bash
  mklink /j G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal D:\pg_wal
  ```
- start the PostgreSQL server

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the same but I'm getting the message as below:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mklink /j G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal D:\pg_wal
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: Then you didn't `move` it. After you `move` `G:\Postgres-14\data\pg_wal` to `D:\pg_wal` it does no longer exist, and `mklink` should succeed.